# How to change sub controls style in a Tab of TabPane using css

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I wanna create a TabPane with some Tabs. If a tab is selected, it shows an image (in the header, not the content), but others will not show the image.
I use the setGraphic method to add an Image, here is my code:

```
       TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.getStyleClass().add("ctab");

        Label value = new Label();
        value.getStyleClass().add("va");
        tab.setGraphic(value);

        tabpane.getTabs().add(tab);
```

Then I write the css to set its style:

```
.va {
    -fx-pref-width: 120;
    -fx-pref-height: 42;
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.ctab:selected>.va {
    -fx-pref-width: 120;
    -fx-pref-height: 42;
    -fx-background-image: url("background.jpg");
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

The tab is selected, but the image is not shown.
I'm so confused about it. Because when the image is in a button, the css works.

```
    Button button= new Button("a");

    button.getStyleClass().add("abtn");

    Label value = new Label("b");
    value.getStyleClass().add("value");

    Label nest = new Label("s");
    nest.getStyleClass().add("nest");

    value.setGraphic(nest);
    button.setGraphic(value);

    root.getChildren().add(button);
```

and the css is:

```
.abtn {
    -fx-pref-width: 120;
    -fx-pref-height: 42;

    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.value {
    -fx-pref-width: 120;
    -fx-pref-height: 42;
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}


.abtn:hover > .value > .nest {
    -fx-pref-width: 120;
    -fx-pref-height: 42;

    -fx-font-size: 20pt;
    -fx-text-fill: black;

    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

When the mouse hover the button, the String "s" size is really changes.
What's the difference between two example? How can I make the tab's image change(use css)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Label` is not owned by the `Tab` directly. Try it out:

```
.ctab:selected > .tab-container > .tab-label > .va
```

As you can see, `setGraphic` is not always intended to set a child node.

[JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) helps you to figure out the structure of controls, but it doesn't have complete list of nodes (for example, `TabPane`'s `tab-container` is not in the list).

To analyze the scene graph structure, CSS Analyzer in Scene Builder and [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) are useful.

---

Or simply the selector below also works.

```
.ctab:selected .va
```